# How to execute an action based on registry values?

Tags: powershell, registry, powershell-2.0

I am having following registry key

```
$rKey="hklm:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Mycompany\MyProj\Core"
```

This key will be having following parameters

```
 DBServer="Installed"
 AppServer="Installed"
 WebServer="Installed"
```

I would like to check

```
 if DBserver="Installed" Then do some action
 Else Do nothing

 If Appserver="Installe" then do some action
 Else Do nothing

 If Webserver ="Installed" then do some action
 Else Do nothing
```

How to get value of property and execute action based on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$p = Get-ItemProperty $key

if($p.DBserver -eq "Installed")
{
   .. do some action ..
}

if($p.Appserver-eq "Installed")
{
   .. do some action ..
}

if($p.Webserver -eq "Installed")
{
   .. do some action ..
}
```